# How to Pass a Variable to Commerce Order Twig Template

Tags: 8, theming, commerce, hooks

I have located commerce-order-receipt.html.twig in commerce/order/templates/ and I have copied it to my theme directory, properly overriding it. My basic changes all work.

Now I am trying to figure out how to pass my own variable to it. I can't figured out which hook_preprocess function I need to use in order to do this. I have figured out how the suggestion and original variables were made in commerce_order.module but this has not helped me hook into it and add more variables.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should work, in **THEME_NAME.theme** add

```
function THEME_NAME_preprocess_commerce_order_receipt(&$variables) {
  $variables['test'] = "test";
}
```

<sub>**Note:** replace THEME_NAME with actual name of theme</sub>

Then doing `{{ test }}` should output "test".

<sub>**Note:** remember to flush all cache to see changes.</sub>